# RPG Management system for running a religion or other internal state system

Tags: realm-management

One of my players has become the head of one of the churches in my world system (Homebrew) and I'd like to add lite-level management and decisions for this to their game; this would involve things like promotions, assigning people to different positions (Inquistor, head paladin, etc) as well as deciding what to do with income from tithes and which temples/other buildings to improve.

At the moment I'm intending on making a hacked up version of the Pathfinders Kingdom management system for this, but is there a system that would let me do this?

It should:

- Allow the player to decide what to add/improve in their church
- Provide positions of authority for their church that have impact on the monthly running of the church
- Be not inherently tied to any one system (I'm running Rolemaster, but steal shamelessly from anything I can get my hands on)

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a shopping question, which we don't handle here. But you can try the chat, they might be able to help.